# Google Translator Toolkit for Android and iOS: how to upload existing translations?

Tags: android, ios, localization, google-translator-toolkit

For Android and iOS:

suppose I start with English as source for translation, I want to translate into French, Italian and Spanish. I already made a lot of translations for these languages, how can I upload them into the toolkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say I have any idea, but I feel bad no one has responded to this point. The best I can do is this documentation [here](https://support.google.com/translate/toolkit/answer/147844?hl=en) for creating and uploading new translation memories.

Unfortunately, since I'm not among the restricted users, I can't access the API documentation.

It seems like Google hasn't done much at all with this offering, but I wish you luck with it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Crowdin.net has this feature. It's a simple feature so I expect the same from Big Google...

Comment: Google though has a history of abandoning big ideas that don't pan out the way they hoped (See Google Wave). I actually read that the final product, as bare bones as it is, is a big step down from their original vision. Meanwhile the Google Groups forum is closing as well. Not looking promising. Still, here is an old [tutorial](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2009-06-09-n19.html) that might help you.